# jQuery find and replace text in a variable

Tags: jquery, html, replace, find

I have a variable like

```
var theUrl = 'http://www.google.com/?q=%s';
```

then i have a input box like

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" value="" />
```

and a button like

```
<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" />
```

when the button is clicked, i should get a alert where the **%s** of the var **theUrl** should be replaced with the user entered text in the textbox

How to do this ? i think find() function only replaces html elements !

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the `replace` function, like this:

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() { 
    alert(theUrl.replace('%s', $('#searchBox').val());
});
```